# How to display content in grid format in django template when receiving dynamic data in terms of list from database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

In django model I have created a multiselectfield for suppose wishlist where user can select multiple wishes from the available choices.

I am storing this data in comma separated format when it comes to displaying this on template things are pretty easy.

But, I want this data to be displayed dynamically as one row with two columns and as soon as two columns are filled and there is more data left to be displayed logic should should have the capability to create a new row and display the remaining content on the django-template.

For reference:

```
# models.py
class Wishlist(models.Model):
    wishlist = (
        ('W1',"Buy a big masion"),
         ('W2',"Buy worlds fastest car"),
          ('W3',"Visit Europe"),
           ('W4',"Travel on bike to mountains")
    )
    
    your_wishlist = MultiSelectField(choices=wishlist)

# views.py
def index(request):
    wishlist = Wishlist.objects.all()
    context = {
        "wishlist":wishlist
    }
    return render(request,'demolistingapp/index.html',context)

# index.html
{% load app_filters %}
{% block content %}
<h1>INDEX LISTING APP</h1>
{% if wishlist %}
    {% for each_wish in wishlist %}
       {% with  each_wish.your_wishlist|split:"," as wish %}
            {% for mywish in wish %}
                <p>{{mywish}}</p><br>
            {% endfor %}
       {% endwith %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I have registered the custom filter split which returns a list.
I want the data to be displayed in terms of grid by maintaining two columns.

Sample output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkteH.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [cycle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle) in the templates to create different class:

```
<p class="{% cycle row_left row_right %}">{{ mywish }}</p>
```

with adequate css (float/clear or inline-block;width:50%).

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap your outer for loop in a HTML element with a class, then apply a grid layout to that class in your stylesheet. Wrapping each wish in a div element with a particular class will help you with further styling too.

```
<div class="wishlist">
    {% for each_wish in wishlist %}
       {% with  each_wish.your_wishlist|split:"," as wish %}
            {% for mywish in wish %}
                <div class="wish">
                    <p>{{mywish}}</p>
                </div>
             {% endfor %}
       {% endwith %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.wishlist {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```